# Support for typesetting a table as stand-alone PDF

Tags: tables, standalone

I'm forced to work in a non-LaTeX workflow but would like to use tables generated with LaTeX. Now I'm looking for support to generate PDFs that contain just a table per page rather than a table on an otherwise empty page that I would have to trim down to the size of the table manually. Does something like this exists? Obviously the page dimensions would depend on the size of the table but LaTeX expects to know the page dimension ahead of time.

Comment: See if the `standalone` package/documentclass` is what you looking for. Also package `preview` can be of help.

Comment: If you provide this as an answer I would consider accepting it. Would like to wait for a few more tips but [`standalone`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) looks promising indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The abstract of documentation for package `standalone` notes:

> The standalone bundle allows users to easily place picture environments
>   or other material in own source files and compile these on their own
>   or as part of a main document. A special standalone class is provided
>   for use with such files, which by default crops the resulting output file to
>   the content. The standalone package enables the user to simply load the
>   standalone files using \input inside a main document.

An example of my test of its use in table design:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs}
    \usepackage{stackengine}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    \usepackage[math]{iwona}% for test purposes only

\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % non-extended bold font
\newcommand{\mybf}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % non-extended bold font
\newcommand{\oklepaj}{(} % non-extended bold font
\robustify\mybf

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r    S[detect-weight,table-format=1.2]
                *{2}{   S[table-space-text-pre=\qquad,
                          detect-weight,table-format=2.1,
                          table-space-text-post=\qquad]}
                *{3}{   S[table-space-text-pre=\quad,
                          detect-weight,table-format=1.1]}}
%
    & \mc{MSRP} & \mc{\stackon{Volume}{Discount}}
        & \mc{\stackon{Allowed}{Promotion}} & \mc{\stackon{Sale}{Discoun}}
            & \mc{\stackon{Sale}{Promotion}} & \mc{\stackon{Sale}{Income}}  \\
    \midrule
\mybf All Round
        &   \mybf 5.49   &   \mybf 30.0  &   \mybf 13.0
            &   \mybf 1.65   &   \mybf 0.71   &   \mybf 2.36 \\
\mybf All Round (suggestion)
        & \mybf 5.49  &  [25.0]  & \mybf 20.0
            & \mybf 1.37  & \mybf 1.10  & \mybf 2.47         \\
    \midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: enter image here]

Generated pdf images you can include in any document which accept them. You can also generate eps images i route latex-dvi-eps (which I never use)